# Why are electrons taking a circuitous path in circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits

[image]

The picture on the right is what happens in real life but, I cant understand why electrons or negative charge carriers have to take this circuitous path to get to the positive charge, If the positive ions are pulling the electrons then shouldn't the positive and negative ions be adhering to the wall separating them within a batter, like in the picture on the left?

Comment: A simple answer would be: batteries are a lot complicated than that

Comment: Where can I learn about battery structure from a physics point of view? any sources or links?

Comment: That would be a chemistry question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a electrochemical reaction inside the battery. The same principle when mistakenly an iron bolt and a copper nut are used in a corrosive enviroment. The reaction direction is for the iron corrodes, nor the copper. If the charges followed the left picture, the reaction would happen in the opposite way.

The circuit, no matter how complicated, is from the battery point of view, only a way to keep the corrosion type reaction running.

Answer (score 1):

The electron which moves in the wire does not come from the battery.. instead, they are already present in the wire even when no battery is connected.. when you connect a battery, it gives those electrons, a straight path to move in a continuous and controlled way...